# is this optional keyword redundant?

Tags: kerberos, asn1

```
KDC-REQ ::= SEQUENCE {
        -- NOTE: first tag is [1], not [0]
        pvno [1] INTEGER (5) ,
        msg-type [2] INTEGER (10 -- AS -- | 12 -- TGS --),
        padata [3] SEQUENCE OF PA-DATA OPTIONAL
            -- NOTE: not empty --,
        req-body [4] KDC-REQ-BODY
}
```

I thought everything in square brackets was optional so why does padata have the word OPTIONAL explicitly as part of its definition?